# Spark scala joining with subquery with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, apache-spark

I need to join two tables on fake_id but table 2 contains more than one matching records for fake_id so I need to match with record where table2.end_time >= table1.event_time and table2.start_time <= table1.event_time
If there are more than one record in table 2 matching this condition, I need to only consider latest by updated_time

Here is what I tried.

`spark.sql("select t1.fake_id, t1.attribute_1,t1.event_time,t22.end_time from table1 t1 left outer join ( 
select fake_id, end_time from table2 t2 where t2.fake_id=t1.fake_id and t2.end_time >= t1.event_time  and t2.start_time <= t1.event_time order by t2.updated_time desc limit 1) 
as t22 on t1.fake_id=t22.fake_id")`

For above statement spark throwing me error for unknown column t1.fake_id

`Table.1 -
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fake_id     attribute_1     event_time
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           attr_val_11     2020-08-01 05:00:00
    2           attr_val_12     2020-08-01 15:00:00 
    3           attr_val_31     2020-08-03 07:00:00
    4           attr_val_41     2020-08-01 05:00:00
    
    Table.2 -
    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fake_id     start_time              end_time                updated_time
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2020-08-01 02:00:00     2020-08-01 08:00:00     2020-08-01 00:00:00
2           2020-08-01 04:00:00     2020-08-01 23:00:00     2020-08-01 00:00:00 
3           2020-08-03 02:00:00     2020-08-03 08:00:00     2020-08-03 08:00:00
3           2020-08-03 05:00:00     2020-08-03 10:00:00     2020-08-03 12:00:00
3           2020-08-04 05:00:00     2020-08-04 10:00:00     2020-08-04 12:00:00
4           2020-08-01 08:00:00     2020-08-01 18:00:00     2020-08-01 18:00:00
4           2020-08-01 02:00:00     2020-08-01 05:00:00     2020-08-01 22:00:00



Result :

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fake_id     attribute_1     event_time              start_time          end_time    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           attr_val_11     2020-08-01 05:00:00     2020-08-01 02:00:00     2020-08-01 08:00:00 
2           attr_val_12     2020-08-01 15:00:00     2020-08-01 04:00:00     2020-08-01 23:00:00
3           attr_val_31     2020-08-03 07:00:00     2020-08-03 05:00:00     2020-08-03 10:00:00
4           attr_val_41     2020-08-01 05:00:00     2020-08-01 02:00:00     2020-08-01 05:00:00`

Comment: I should have probably added this additional filter for time range before posting this question. Apologies for adding this late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `between` and get the `row_number`, sort and take the maximum update time.

```
spark.sql('''
    select
        fake_id,
        attribute_1,
        event_time,
        start_time,
        end_time
    from (
        select 
            t1.fake_id, 
            t1.attribute_1,
            t1.event_time,
            t2.start_time,
            t2.end_time,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.fake_id, t1.attribute_1 ORDER BY t2.updated_time DESC) as rank
        from 
            table1 t1
        left join
            table2 t2
        on
          t1.fake_id = t2.fake_id and 
          t1.event_time between t2.start_time and t2.end_time) t
    where 
        rank = 1
    order by 
        fake_id
''').show()


+-------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|fake_id|attribute_1|         event_time|         start_time|           end_time|
+-------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      1|attr_val_11|2020-08-01 05:00:00|2020-08-01 02:00:00|2020-08-01 08:00:00|
|      2|attr_val_12|2020-08-01 15:00:00|2020-08-01 04:00:00|2020-08-01 23:00:00|
|      3|attr_val_31|2020-08-03 07:00:00|2020-08-03 05:00:00|2020-08-03 10:00:00|
|      4|attr_val_41|2020-08-01 05:00:00|2020-08-01 02:00:00|2020-08-01 05:00:00|
+-------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your comments.. I had to include additional filter and a new column for start_time in original problem. I think subquery will not fit this scenario.